# Basic MySQL SELECT Query running extremely slowly

Tags: mysql, performance

I've linked a MySQL view into MS Access via ODBC, but it's running WAY slow.

It's a simple select, that compares two other selects to find records that are unique to the first select.

```
SELECT `contacts_onlinedonors`.`contactkey` AS `contactkey`
FROM   (`hal9k3-testbed`.`contacts_onlinedonors`
    LEFT JOIN `hal9k3-testbed`.`contacts_offlinedonors`
      ON(( `contacts_onlinedonors`.`contactkey` =
         `contacts_offlinedonors`.`contactkey` )))
WHERE  Isnull(`contacts_offlinedonors`.`contactkey`)
```

The slow query log says it returns 34,000 rows after examining 1.5 Billion.  There are only 200,000 in the base table.  What the heck?

The field "contactkey" is obviously an index on the table.

Comment: I suspect the problem is related to "I've linked a MySQL view into MS Access via ODBC".  When you run the MySQL query directly, is it slow?

Comment: And the title said basic... Do an EXPLAIN on the query.

Comment: contactkey is an index on which table - offlinedonors or onlinedonors?

Answer (score 2):

First thing to do is to "explain" this query.
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

The idea is to figure out what the mysql server is doing, which indexes it is using, and adding indexes where needed, or rewriting your query so it can use indexes.